# Querying nested array in mngoose with elemMatch

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I have a service, where I try to query a nested array inside a mongoose document like such

```js
async getSpecificRating(raterId: string, ratedPersonId: string){
    const _specificRating = await this.ratingModel.findOne({ratedPersonId: ratedPersonId})
    console.log(_specificRating) //finds the rating succesfully
    console.log(_specificRating.ratings[0].raterId === raterId) //logs true
    const speceficRating = await this.ratingModel.find({ratedPersonId: ratedPersonId}).elemMatch("ratings", {raterId: raterId}) //returns the entire object, not just the nested rating object
    return speceficRating
}
```

I can successfully find the `ratingModel`, but when I try to query the ratings (nested array of objects), I can't seem to access the specific rating with my condition.

How can I only return the nested object, and not the entire document?

EDIT:

This is the current json output I get in return from my query  in the third line of my function `console.log(_specificRating) //finds the rating succesfully`.

```
{ ratings:
   [ { raterId: '130',
       rating: 8,
       timeSpent: 1970-01-01T00:00:12.507Z,
       timestamp: 2009-02-17T01:35:45.454Z,
       userThreshold: 7 } ],
  _id: 5f78b8261e1d777319b6ab11,
  ratedPersonId: '129',
```

It returns the entire object, with the full array of `ratings` (in this case, there is only one. What I instead want, is that I only want the specific object in the ratings array where the `raterId` is equal to, what I have passed into my function

I would like the return type to `only be a single entry, where the query matches like shown below`

```
{ raterId: '130',
       rating: 8,
       timeSpent: 1970-01-01T00:00:12.507Z,
       timestamp: 2009-02-17T01:35:45.454Z,
       userThreshold: 7 }
```

Comment: Can you please add input and expected output JSON. Is MongoDB query fine for you?

Comment: @Mallik yes anything would do i will update the question

Comment: @Mallik what do you mean sample array input?

Comment: sorry, I mean sample JSON input having at least two documents.